# How to add Application Icon to an ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to list all installed applications in an `expandableListView` with the corresponding icons of the applications. The list of installed applications works, but I have got no matter, how to insert the applications icons for the ListView.

Here is my code of the `expandableListView`:

```
public class GestureAnyWhere extends ExpandableListActivity {

private ArrayList<String> elternElemente = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Object> kindElemente = new ArrayList<Object>();
...
 ExpandableListView liste_schritt1 = getExpandableListView ();

    // Zeilenabstand bestimmen
    liste_schritt1.setDividerHeight ( 10 );

    // Pfeil an der Seite rechts anzeigen lassen durch setGroupIndicator
   // liste_schritt1.setGroupIndicator ( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.expandiconempty) );
    liste_schritt1.setClickable ( true );

    elternElementTexte ();
    kindElementTexte();

    MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(elternElemente, kindElemente);

    adapter.setInflater ( ( LayoutInflater ) getSystemService ( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE ), this );
    liste_schritt1.setAdapter ( adapter );
    liste_schritt1.setOnChildClickListener ( this );

...
 private void elternElementTexte(){

    elternElemente.add("Anwendung starten");


}


private void kindElementTexte(){

    ArrayList<String> kinder = new ArrayList<String>();

    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo > packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    String packetName = null;

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {


        packetName = packageInfo.packageName;

        kinder.add(packetName);
    }

    kindElemente.add(kinder);
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 1):

Call [`loadIcon()` on the `ApplicationInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#loadIcon%28android.content.pm.PackageManager%29), passing in your `PackageManager` as a parameter, to get the `Drawable` to put into the `ImageView`.